# C Programming - how to match an end character of a String?

Tags: c, regex

How to match an end character of a string ?

Here is my code :

```
int ownRegex(char* str_request, char* str_regex) {
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_NOSUB | REG_EXTENDED);

  if (!err) {
    int match;
    match = regexec(&preg, str_request, 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&preg);

    if (!match)
        return 0;
    else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
        return match;
    else {
        char *text;
        size_t size;

        size = regerror(err, &preg, NULL, 0);
        text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * size);
        if (text) {
            regerror (err, &preg, text, size);
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", text);
            free(text);
        } else
            fprintf(stderr, "im");
        exit(errno);
    }
  }
  return err;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to match those lines:

"**GET / HTTP/1.1**" or "**GET / HTTP/1.0**", so I use the regex "**^GET / HTTP/1\.[01]$**"

Because I don't want a parasite word after the HTTP version like "**GET / HTTP/1.1** *blablabla*".

But when I'm using this regex none of the lines I try match.

**[EDIT]**

So here is how I call my function:

```
int match = ownRegex(clientMessage, "^GET / HTTP/1\\.[01]$");
if (match)
    printf("400\n");
else
    printf("200\n");
```

(I've simplified the code)

And here is the lines I tried :
`

1. "**GET / HTTP/1.1**" -> return 400, should be 200
2. "**GET / HTTP/1.0**" -> return 400, should be 200
3. "**GET / HTTP/1a1**" -> return 400
4. "**GET / HTTP/1.2**" -> return 400
5. "**AGET / HTTP/1.1**" -> return 400
6. "**A GET / HTTP/1.1**" -> return 400
7. "**GET / HTTP/1.1 TEST**" -> return 400
8. "**GET / HTTP//1.1**" -> return 400
9. "**GET / HTTP/ 1.1**" -> return 400

So only the two first lines are supposed correct, but only the n°3 to 9 have te correct return because my function always return 400.

Also if I remove the '$' in my regex, all the lines have the correct return except the n°7.

I hope I have clarified my question :).

**[END EDIT]**

Have you any idea what I did wrong ?

Thanks for reading me,and sorry for my english.

Comment: show the regex string you use in the C code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a [mcve]. You are showing neither the regex nor the text you want to match. Yes, you explained what it is, but you must show us the code that does it.

Comment: `"^GET / HTTP/1\\.[01]$"` should work. You may also use `"^GET / HTTP/1[.][01]$"`

Comment: Could you modify first print to output also actual `match` value and show us them as well?

Comment: It seems to work - https://ideone.com/qXbD5E

Comment: @SergGr the match value is always equal to 1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Strange, maybe because I'm using buffer array of 1024 to recept the data from the client, gonna check that. Thanks

Comment: Mike, any news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Well, thanks to @WiktorStribiżew who made me realize something, my char array always end with **'\r\n'** or **'\n'** not only **'\0'** like a literal String.

So I just had to modify my regex:

`match = ownRegex(clientMessage, "^GET / HTTP/1\\.[01]\r{0,1}\n");`

Bye.